# Set the thickness width of the blinking cursor

Tags: autohotkey, caret, thickness

Is it possible to use Autohotkey or other script to set thickness width of the blinking cursor?

This setting can be manually operated by the following steps in WIN7:

Control Panel-> Ease of Access Center->Make the computer easier to see->Set the thickness of the blinking cursor

Comment: You can set it in the registry: **HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop**: Change **CaretWidth** to a value between 1 and 20 (decimal).

Comment: Hi MCL: Thanks for you prompt reply. That's what i want. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer. Please accept it, so that your problem is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it in the registry.
**HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop**: Change **CaretWidth** to a value between **1** and **20** (decimal).